# Trying to make a configurable polka dot background using just CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid background out of dots. I can't just use an image, because I need everything to be configurable:

- background color
- dot color
- dot size
- space between dots

Unless there's a better solution, I think the only way I can achieve this is with pure CSS. I've done some looking around and so far the closest thing i've found is using a radial-gradient. I'm having trouble though; I haven't been able to find a solution that lets me configure both the dot size and the space between dots while keeping a circle shape. I've gotten close, but than my dots end up looking like diamonds instead of circles. Here's what i've come up with so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/yzpuydtn/

```
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 2px, white 2px);
  background-size:40px 40px;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Initially i'd like to have my dots be 2px x 2px and 40 px apart. Is there a better way to do this, or am I just configuring my gradient incorrectly? I think i'm close, but depending on how I zoom they look like either circles, diamonds or squares and I need it to always look like circles.

Comment: I'd just use SVG; then it's scalable and shouldn't deform when zooming.

Comment: If I use an SVG, can I adjust colors and dimensions on the fly?

Comment: You can interact with SVG via [the DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html), just as you can HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using %: https://jsfiddle.net/yzpuydtn/11/ 
Using vw: http://jsfiddle.net/otwhu0uk/2/

Here is an example. I really hope this helps you.

```
body {
  /* Controls size of dot */
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 5%, white 0%);
  /* Controls Spacing, First value will scale width, second, height between dots */
  background-size:5% 10%;
}
```

Comment: Please read again the question. And than explain in your answer how you managed to get perfect circles at any size and distance.

Comment: Sorry, rushed my answer. The reason they are perfect circles is, because I am using percentages instead of pixels as units. I will be looking into properly answering your question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how your answer code is *configurable* and how `%` could make any difference https://jsfiddle.net/yzpuydtn/1/

Comment: I need the dots to be 2px x 2px. If it's 20% that's not the case, right? Is there some way to specify what number the 20% is relative to?

Comment: Yes, the 20% is relevant to which container the dots are in. So if you have a div that has a width set to 100px, then 2% of that will be 2px. Quick question, are you going for a diamond pattern polka dot or just in the square pattern that you have right now in your jsFiddle?

Comment: I want a grid of circles. Basically the exact thing I have in the fiddle but circles.

Comment: Almost forgot! There is also a cool unit called vm. It will make your polka dots non-scalable. Does not matter what width, they will be very constant. Here is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/otwhu0uk/1/

Comment: Hmm very cool!  if i'm adding this background to a div that has height: 200 and width: 500, what would I set the VM value to if I want my 2x2 dots that are 20px apart?

Comment: Sorry, the unit is called vw. It is a unit that is relative to 1% of the width of the viewport. % on the other hand goes off of the width of the container.